# holomorph vs having a primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, and $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$

I know that if $f$ is holomorph, then $f'$ is holomorph, and so derivatives of all orders exists.

I know that beeing holomorph is not enough to have a primitive, for example $f(z) = 1/z$ is holomorph but does not have a primitive in $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$

My question is, if $f$ has a primitive, let's say $F$ (so that $F' = f$), then does it mean that $F$ has a primitive too? (so if it have a primitive, it has primitives of all orders).  If it's true, how is it proven? If it isn't, which function is a counterexample?

Thanks!

Comment: Just after I wrote it I think I found a counterexample, if $f(z) = 1/z$ then $f'(z) = -1/z^2$,  Lets call $g(z) = -1/z^2$, then $g$ has a primitive $G(z) = 1/z$ but $G$ doesn't have a primitive.  So the answer to my question is that there doesn't necesarily exist primitive of all orders.  Is this correct?

Comment: And I think it is true if $U$ is simply connected: because of cauchy theorem if $f$ is holomorph and $U$ simply connected then $f$ has a primitive $F$, and $F$ is holomorph so it has another primitive, etc.  Is this right too?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it at your disposal! For any function $f$ which doesn't have a primitive, take its derivative. Voila!